# What anti-virus solution works with Windows Server 8 beta?

Tags: anti-virus, ms-security-essentials, windows-server-2012

Testing out beta Windows Server 8. Would like to install a free antivirus, but MSE doesn't seem to support it yet and can't find one that does. Know of one?

Comment: MSE doesn't support Windows Server 2008 R2. Any anti-virus that supports Windows Server 2008 R2 would likely support Windows Server 8.  I should add that Windows 8 itself has the next version of MSE built into it, so MSE will never support Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

There's architectural differences between 2008 R2 and Server 8 so I'd actually assume that many antivirus products for 2008R2/7 will NOT work.
(For now I've only tested Symantec Endpoint Protection 11, and that crashes)

MSE is rebranded as "Windows Defender" and is included with Windows 8. Note however that Defender is not included in the server edition of Windows 8!
Here you'll probably need the Forefront client or whatever equivalent version Microsoft comes up with.